# Does Discover place icons on the Desktop?

Tags: desktop-icons, discover-software-center

Should Discover automatically put icons for programs it installs on the Desktop? Or is it usually the program's installation program that does this, provided the program's developer intended there be one?

My OS is Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1

Comment: It's the package post-installation script that will do/not-do it.  Discover's job is to show a list of packages that are available for install, and install/remove them   (ie. you should get identical results if you used Discover or `muon` which is an alternate package manager included with Ubuntu Studio/Lubuntu.. 22.04.1 - https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/22.04.1/release/ubuntustudio-22.04.1-dvd-amd64.manifest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not the software center (e.g. Discover) that does install icons. It is the installation script of the application you install that does that, though never on your desktop.

In Linux, the correct places to install program launchers are in the "applications" directories under one of the directories included in the XDG_DATA_DIRS environmental variable. This is where the menu system of your desktop will find the launchers, and present them in the menu.

Therefore, (correctly behaving) installation scripts will, if the developer opted to install launchers, do that in one of these locations. For APT this is `/usr/share/applications`, and for Snap applications `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications`.